# How to change a registration within a scope?

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac, unit-of-work

My main Autofac registration registers UnitOfWork and services as follows:

```
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>()
    .As(typeof(IUnitOfWork))
    .InstancePerDependency();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

Everything works fine with this setup.

Now I have a scenario where I create a scope as follows:

```
using (var scope = lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var customerService = scope.Resolve<ICustomerService>();
}
```

However, in this particular scenario I would like to change the registration of `UnitOfWork` to `SingleInstance` so that any services created inside the scope get the same unit of work instance.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.  I'm not sure, at this stage.

Comment: [Have you read the docs?](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html#adding-registrations-to-a-lifetime-scope)